Can I grow wisteria on sand?
I'm planning to plant Wisteria next to my house. After I removed concrete slabs that were next to the wall, I noticed there was a deep layer of building sand underneath.
I'm planning to cover it with a couple of cm of soil and plant wisteria, but I'm a bit worried it will not grow well.
Should I remove all that sand and replace it with soil, or can the wisteria roots handle this without major problems?

The question you might actually want to ask is: Can your house handle the roots and the vines?

Wisteria is part of the Legume family, meaning it can produce nitrates VIA the Atmosphere, thus can grow quickly in poor quality soils but still needs a Phosphate/potassium rich fertilizer. With two species, both make poisonous seeds.
Also the plant unless you live in China/Japan is invasive, If you live in North America best disposed of

Legumes do not release nitrates in the atmosphere; bacteria living in specialized root growths take nitrogen gas molecules from the atmosphere, break them up and convert them into nitrates that plants can use. Other plants have to make do with nitrates released by decaying organic matter.

I would replace the sand with good potting soil, as the sand lacks organic matter and will not hold water very well.
